# What arguments does eqgame.exe take on the command line?

Tags: everquest

Just wondering what arguments `eqgame.exe` takes on the command line? I'm needing to [bypass the Launcher since it doesn't work on Linux with DXVK (OpenGL's Vulcan).](https://github.com/doitsujin/dxvk/issues/1824)

Answer (score 2):

Seems to take the following commands,

- `nosou`
- `patchme`
- `/ticket:`
- `/login:`
- `/locale:`
- `/name:`
- `/server:`
- `/port:`

My version, on Linux with Wine gets invoked with `patchme` and `/ticket:`.